# How to increase performance of Android AR scene

Tags: unity, android, performance, augmented-reality

I'm wondering how to improve speed on this scene for AR on Android, since it's still sluggish. From what I could see, Unity instanced the particle system meshes automatically (is that correct?).

I'm a 3D modeler learning to code, therefore my expertise is limited.

**Specs**
2300 faces, 1 texture 1024x1024.png for coral and fish

[image: Screenshot of scene]

Comment: Did you try [profiling](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/profiler-profiling-applications.html) your project to find out where the bottleneck really is? Perhaps the model is fine and the reason for the bad performance actually lies somewhere completely different.

Comment: Thanks Phillip, that helps, I'll check at it. do you know some decent beginner tutorials? Never used profiler - but I guess i'm about to learn them :P